# IBM WebSphere deploy Angular 5 application and getting 404 on refresh

Tags: java, linux, angular, unix, websphere

I build full stack applications with Angular (currently version 5)  Usually the backend is `Windows Server` and it uses `IIS`  , so thus I know to deploy a web.config file with the rewrite module code.

Problem is that the site is a SPA , and it needs to always point at index.html, no matter what the URL says...

As I said, I'm used to windows , but the backend is Java with `IBM Websphere`

Anyone know what I need to have done in order to have a properly working Angular application?

Example, the configuration for WINDOWS is a web.config like this below, but this is Websphere with a Java application and I assume the backend is `Linux/unix`

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp/" />
      <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the following to web.xml, which is packaged in the WEB_INF directory within the .war file of your app:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

Which tells the app server to show the resource at the application's context root when issuing a 404 error.

Comment: Thx,  let me ask the guy in the team to try that

Comment: Cool.  email I got back from an developer was "Hi, Tom

Thank you for looking into this. Yes, this resolves 404 error¬, I have deployed a new version with the fix to dev. Somehow it even takes care of basic navigation with “back”, “forward” buttons and address bar, not sure why, need to look closer into this. "        Thanks,

Comment: Navigation works because Angular's router module parses the URL and pattern matches it against your configured routes. It also uses some calls introduced in HTML5 to manipulate the browser history stack so each route change looks like a real page navigation.